# Disconnected boundaries of connected sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

$A, B$ are bounded, connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with non-empty interiors. Consider their shared boundary, i.e. the set:

$$S:= bd\;A \cap bd\;B$$

Define:

$$
S_1 = \{(x,x):x \in [0.2,0.3]\}\\
S_2 = \{(x,x):x \in [0.4,0.5]\}.
$$

It is given that (1) $S_1$ and $S_2$ are subsets of $S$, (2) the boundary points of $S_1$ and $S_2$ are boundary points of $S$ and (3) $\{(x,x):x \in (0.3,0.4)\}\cap S = \emptyset$.

My question is: Can we say that there exist two paths -- say $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ -- between the "top" endpoint of $S_1,(0.3,0.3),$ and the "bottom" endpoint of $S_2,(0.4,0.4),$ such that $\gamma_1 \subseteq bd\;A$, $\gamma_2 \subseteq bd\;B$ and $\gamma_1 \cap \gamma_2 = \{(0.3,0.3),(0.4,0.4)\}$?

I have basic knowledge of metric spaces and topology but I'm new to the notions of connectedness and paths. A picture is attached to capture the way I've visualized this so far. Any help is most appreciated.
[image: Picture]

Comment: Why do there have to be *two* paths?  Couldn't you just have one there so long as it avoided $\{(x,x):x \in (0.3,0.4)\}$ and was still part of the boundaries of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: My apologies. I didn't quite understand. I've edited the question to add a picture of how I'm visualizing the situation, including gamma_1 and gamma_2 - the two parts of the boundaries of A and B "around" the part of the y=x line we've "taken out". But I'm afraid I may not be capturing everything that can happen! Could you elaborate further what you mean? Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not always - it depends on what $A$ and $B$ are. You've drawn it in a way that makes $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ exist. But if you take $A = B$ to be a set that looks like the following:

[image]

Here, $S = \text{bd}(A) = \text{bd}(B)$ is just the boundary, and we can see that all the initial conditions are met. There is no way to draw a path from $(0.3,0.3)$ to $(0.4,0.4)$ that remains in $S$ since $S$ is not connected.

Comment: Thank you so much! As I said I'm very new to connectedness. If we say A and B are simply connected instead, and A =/= B, does the statement hold? thanks again.

Comment: It still might not be enough. The way I'm thinking about it is that one way for $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ to exist is if the boundary of $A$ and $B$ is path connected. So the question is whether the boundary of a bounded, simply connected set is path connected. You might be able to construct something similar to the Warsaw circle where $\text{bd}(A)$ is not path connected even if $A$ is simply connected (see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4219329/given-any-bounded-simply-connected-regular-open-set-on-the-plane-is-the-bound)

Comment: Thank you so much! I later realized that boundaries of A and B to be path connected is necessary. The conditions I have given are, of course, not enough for that. Thank you again!

Comment: But unfortunately I do not understand the proof, i.e. why path connectedness of the boundaries of A and B lead to the existence of $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$. Should I ask a separate question about it? Thank you!

Comment: If the boundary of $A$ is path connected, then there exists a path that connects any two points on the boundary. Since $(0.3,0.3)$ and $(0.4,0.4)$ are both in the boundary of $A$, then there is a path which connects the two points, and this might be the $\gamma_1$ you're looking for. You could do the same for $B$ to find a $\gamma_2$. However, Henry's point seems to be correct in that these paths could both be the same, so you won't get the condition $\gamma_1 \cup \gamma_2 = \{ (0.3,0.3),(0.4,0.4) \}$, so you might need stronger conditions on $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Sorry I mean $\gamma_1 \cap \gamma_2$.

Answer (score 1):

My question in the comments "Why do there have to be *two* paths?" came from the thought that it was possible there was just one path, as in

[image]